# Multi-step sign-up form sails JS

Tags: forms, sails.js

I'm trying to create a 4 steps sign-up form with sails JS.

At this moment, the form is fully working when i try it with postman with all required inputs in the same request. Now I'm creating the view associated to the form an I would like to seperate the sign up in 4 step, in this way :

- 1st step : `email` & `password` required -> Creating the entry in the db -> *next page*
- 2nd step (optional) : `zipCode` (required if an `input` is not defined in the route called) -> *next page*
- 3rd step : showing the associated "Partner" to the user depending on the zip code at step 2 -> updating the entry in the dB -> *next page*
- 4th step : optional `name`, `firstname` -> Updating the entry in the db, sending confirm mail -> *End of the sign up form*

Do I have to create 4 seperate controller ?  I'm new to sails and nodejs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, 4 routes, 4 controller actions.

Comment: Nice, it's working this way, i've finished the step 2, thank you. I have one more question, is-it necessary then to create a page for each step (at this moment, this is how i do 1 controller / view / page / js file by step) or could I do it with only one page and one GET request ?

Comment: Thats very specific, but you can do it like an API and a single page...